# Bind nested route to Model in ASP.NET MVC4 API controller

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a GET request with URL which is http://foo.com/accounts/123/users/456. For the API Controller, the routing will be like:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "DefaultApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/accounts/{accountid}/users/{userid}",
   defaults: new { accountid = RouteParameter.Optional, userid = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The controller will like:

```
public string Get(string accountid, string userid)
{
     ....
}
```

So, rather than receive two parameters, is that possible to make the controller to receive one object which contains these parameters like:

```
public string Get(Query query)
{
    string accountid = query.AccountID;
    string userid= query.UserID;
}
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  From the [ASP.NET site](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api):

> By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:
>
> If the parameter is a “simple” type, Web API tries to get the value from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types
>   (int, bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid,
>   decimal, and string, plus any type with a type converter that can
>   convert from a string. (More about type converters later.)
>
> For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type formatter.

Comment: I know the url with parameters like "http://localhost/api/values/?userid=123&accountid=456" can be be converted to a object. However, my question is how to convert http://foo.com/accounts/123/users/456 to object. I want to use the route to carry the parameters rather than some thing like ?userid=123&accountid=456. Any ideas?